# Reverse Queryset Order in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

Is there any simple way to reverse the order of a queryset in Django?

Example:

```py
li = [1, 2, 3]

queryset = Collection.objects.filter(pk__in=li)
```

Comment: what about using `order_by()`?

Comment: How would I flip an already made queryset though? I'm not really ordering by anything. Would order_by(-) work?

Comment: It's in some kind of order, even if you're not specifying it in your query. It might be specified in the model or just going by the pk as a default. You could `order_by(-pk)` in the default case, I think. If the queryset is not too big, you can do it in memory in Python by casting it to a list and doing `[::-1]` slice or using `reversed`.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It is certainly not ordered by `pk` by default. Unless the order is specified in some way, a queryset is unordered, i.e. an arbitrary order with no guarantees whatsoever.

Comment: @knbk OK, an implementation detail then. I was trying to raise the point that if it's not in any kind of order now (not guaranteed as you say), reversing it will not change that. When I call a queryset from virtually any model in the Django implementations I have within reach right now, if I don't specify, it gives it to me in the order I put them in the database, which is by pk (note I'm only talking about using a serial field here -- no idea for custom primary keys). Whether this is by design or by accident I do not know.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist They can often appear to be ordered on pk. The exact order is dependant on many factors, most importantly the order rows are physically stored on disk. If you only ever insert rows with a serial pk, it is likely that a result set has the same order, but that's not an assumption you can rely on. I get that it is not your main point, but it's an important distinction, and a very common misconception.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use

```
queryset = reversed(Collection.objects.filter(pk__in = li))
```

or

```
queryset = Collection.objects.filter(pk__in = li).reverse()
```

Comment: Does it require reload of server to make the changes?

Comment: @RamisaAnjumAditi server reloads automatically if you make any changes.

Comment: Take care: If you use `reverse()` the result of the queryset may change. Tested in `django==1.11.17`
I went for `list(reversed(qs))`

Comment: `reverse()` should not be used without first using `order_by()`. Otherwise you are reversing on unordered QuerySet, which doesn't make any sense and WILL provide inconsistent results.

Comment: reversed() works like charmmm

Answer (score 9):

To reverse qs

```
queryset = Collection.objects.filter(pk__in = li).order_by('field_name')
```

If for some reason you don't want to use order_by then  reverse list

```
queryset = Collection.objects.filter(pk__in = li)
result = reversed(list(queryset))
```